# Locking a door in Inform7 works in one case but not another

Tags: inform7

Hoping there is someone active on this tag I will issue a problem regarding Inform7 here. We currently use this language in college to get in contact with the structure of splicing projects and tasks in a group.

The current task is to unlock a door when a button is pressed and close it after one turn. The code I use is the following:

```
doorOpen is a number which varies. doorOpen is 0. [ = false]

TuerK is a door. It is south of Flur006R and north of R028a. It is locked.
Tbutton_flur is in Flur006R. Tbutton_flur can be pushed.
Instead of pushing Tbutton_flur:
    now TuerK is unlocked;
    say "Die Tür öffnet sich";
    now doorOpen is 2;

Every turn when doorOpen is 1:
    now doorOpen is 0;
    now TuerK is locked;
    say "Door closes!".

Every turn when doorOpen is 2:
    decrement doorOpen.

Tbutton_raum is in R028a. Tbutton_raum can be pushed.
Instead of pushing Tbutton_raum:
    now TuerK is unlocked;
    say "Door opens!";
    now doorOpen is 2;
```

Where I use doorOpen as an attribute to check whether the door was open or not. Problem now is that I can push the button, go to the opened room, it says that the door is beeing closed, but I can go out of the room without any problems and it appears that it is unlocked from now on.

On the other hand I have other code:

TuerSiT is a door. It is south of R024 and north of Flur005R. It is locked.

The Sicherheitsausweis unlocks TuerSiT.

```
Before going to R024:
    if player is holding Sicherheitsausweis:
        now TuerSiT is unlocked;
        say "Der Sicherheitsausweis hat die Tür entsperrt";
    otherwise:
        now TuerSiT is locked.
```

Where the `now doorname is locked` works totally fine.

Is there anything I did incorrectly? I also tried to create hidden keys to have the unlocked because that was where I thought the problem was, but it seems I am unable to lock the door.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears the one first has to close the door, which was something I did not test on the other door. So

```
now the door is closed;
now the door is locked.
```

works all fine.

Comment: Indeed, openness and lockedness are separate properties. I would expect that locking the door like you were doing was in effect locking it open.

Comment: Yeah I got that, but I thought that locking implied closing it first. If I would hand you a key place you in front of an open door and told you to lock it, you would not turn the key pull it out and go away leaving the door open so that was what confused me. Thanks for the added explanation!

Comment: I don't think that level of modelling is included by default - IIRC locking only controls whether you're allowed to open or close the object. You can check the Standard Rules to see exactly what happens though.